# How to run something in the STA thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sta

In my WPF application I do some async communication (with server). In the callback function I end up creating InkPresenter objects from the result from server. This requires the running thread to be STA, which apparently it currently isn't. Therefore I get the following exception:

> Cannot create instance of 'InkPresenter' defined in assembly [..] The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

Currently my async function call is like this:

```
public void SearchForFooAsync(string searchString)
{
    var caller = new Func<string, Foo>(_patientProxy.SearchForFoo);
    caller.BeginInvoke(searchString, new AsyncCallback(SearchForFooCallbackMethod), null);
}
```

How can I make the callback - which will do the InkPresenter creation - be STA? Or invoke the XamlReader parsing in a new STA thread.

```
public void SearchForFooCallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var foo = GetFooFromAsyncResult(ar); 
    var inkPresenter = XamlReader.Parse(foo.Xaml) as InkPresenter; // <!-- Requires STA
    [..]
}
```

Comment: Whatever happened to `[STAThread]` before a method?  Not always appropriate but very easy.  Maybe it didn't come out till 2011?  I haven't used it since 2011 that I recall...

Comment: Adding [STAThread] before the method worked for me. Thank you, ebyrob! :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can start STA Threads like so:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(MethodWhichRequiresSTA);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
    thread.Start(); 
    thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
```

The only problem is that your result object must be passed along somehow.. You can use a private field for that, or dive into passing along parameters into threads. Here I set the foo data in a private field and start up the STA Thread to mutate the inkpresenter!

```
private var foo;
public void SearchForFooCallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    foo = GetFooFromAsyncResult(ar); 
    Thread thread = new Thread(ProcessInkPresenter);
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join(); 
}

private void ProcessInkPresenter()
{
    var inkPresenter = XamlReader.Parse(foo.Xaml) as InkPresenter;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks :) Let me know if it will fix the problem. We use this technique to generate PNG images of our Xaml controls on the server!

Comment: Seems to fix the problem, but just met another problem. *Sigh*.. Will mark as accepted as soon as I get everything working here.. Thx!

Comment: @Arcturus: what is `MethodWhichRequiresSTA` just a method? my code will not compile if I put a method there since it needs its arguments

Comment: Can you please provide an example of method MethodWhichRequiresSTA?

Comment: Sorry for a late post - but what is GetFooFromAsyncResult?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class to execute the method call on the UI-Thread. The Dispatcher provides the static property CurrentDispatcher to get the dispatcher of a thread.

If your object of the class, that creates the InkPresenter, is created on the UI-Thread, then the CurrentDispatcher method returns the Dispatcher of the UI-Thread.

On the Dispatcher you can call the BeginInvoke-method to call the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke or BeginInvoke is the way to go. Much simpler than the accepted solution

Comment: Should be wary of using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` unless you are certain you are running on a UI thread that will be processing `DispatcherOperation`s. `CurrentDispatcher` will create a dispatcher for the current thread if it doesn't already have one, even if the current thread is MTA. I usually find it better to use the `Dispatcher` property on the control I want to update.

Answer (score 3):

It should be good enough to call it on the UI thread. Therefore, use a `BackgroundWorker` and on the `RunWorkerAsyncCompleted`, you can then do the creation of the inkPresenter.

Comment: You're right. Problem is that the callback isn't run on the UI thread. The UI thread is run with STA, so running it on the UI thread should solve this for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but I would use [XTATestRunner](http://xtatestrunner.codeplex.com) So your code will look like:

```
    public void SearchForFooAsync(string searchString)
    {
        var caller = new Func<string, Foo>(_patientProxy.SearchForFoo);
        caller.BeginInvoke(searchString, new AsyncCallback(SearchForFooCallbackMethod), null);
    }

    public void SearchForFooCallbackMethod(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var foo = GetFooFromAsyncResult(ar); 
        InkPresenter inkPresenter;
        new XTATestRunner().RunSTA(() => {
            inkPresenter = XamlReader.Parse(foo.Xaml) as InkPresenter;
        });
    }
```

as a bonus it's possible to catch exceptions thrown in STA (or MTA) thread like this:

```
try
{
    new XTATestRunner().RunSTA(() => {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    });
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just used the following to get clipboard content from the STA thread. Thought I would post to maybe help someone in the future...

```
string clipContent = null;
Thread t = new Thread(
    () =>
    {
        clipContent = Clipboard.GetText();
    });
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();

// do stuff with clipContent

t.Abort();
```