# How to override window show operation?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class derived from window to show  message to user. The problem is in some places in my application it is throwing an exception saying

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require
>   this.

I came to know i need to introduce the Dispatcher to invoke the messagebox to get rid of the error.  Since the messagebox is used in numerous locations the fastest fix i can think about is to override the show and showwindow and create and display the message box from there.

Please tell me how can i override the Show and ShowWindow events of a wpf window

Comment: You can't.  It isn't marked virtual...  Maybe someone will have an alternative for you tho.

Comment: This link to a similar question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378016/how-to-run-something-in-the-sta-thread

Comment: public new bool? ShowDialog() { /* etc */ }

Comment: Is it possible to  set the ApartmentState.STA in the constructor of the window class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a static utility class that has a method (and maybe some overloads) to show this form for you. A bit like `MessageBox` in Windows.Forms. Within that class you can code anything that is required to show the window properly without ever having to repeat yourself.