# RichTextBox - InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be STA

Tags: c#, wpf, ajax, multithreading, richtextbox

I'm trying to use this [**Converting between RTF and HTML**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e) library from MSDN to convert some RTF text to HTML. The jist of my setup is an AJAX call from JavaScript to a C# handler which calls this `MarkupConverter` library to do the conversion, then write back the HTML.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "MyHandler.ashx",
   data: richTextData,
   success: function (html) {
            alert('success, html: ' + html);
   },
   error: function (msg) {
            alert("error: " + msg);
   }
});
```

And the code from my handler, which is also very simple:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   if (context.Request.Form.Count > 0)
   {
      string rtf = context.Request.Form[0];
      string html = "";
      if (rtf != "")
      {
         markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
         html = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtf);
      }
      if (html != "")
      {
         context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
         context.Response.Write(html);
      }
      else
      {
         context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
         context.Response.Write("Error from RTF2HTML");
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is, every time this runs, an Exception is thrown because the `RichTextBox` control is getting created on a background thread:

> [InvalidOperationException: The calling thread must be STA, because
>   many UI components require this.]
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager..ctor() +11032206
>   System.Windows.Input.InputManager.GetCurrentInputManagerImpl() +125
>   System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation..ctor() +185
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.EnsureFrameworkServices() +109
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement..ctor() +504
>   System.Windows.Controls.Control..ctor() +87
>   System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox..ctor(FlowDocument document) +56
>   MarkupConverter.RtfToHtmlConverter.ConvertRtfToXaml(String rtfText)
>   +67    MarkupConverter.RtfToHtmlConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(String rtfText) +23    MyHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +416

I thought maybe because the AJAX call is asychronous, the call is getting placed on a background thread. So I changed it to this:

```
var postText = $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "RTF2HTML.ashx",
   data: textData,
   async: false
}).responseText;
alert(postText);
```

But even still when I check the current thread in my handler:

```
context.Response.Write("thread: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState().ToString());
```

It still returns MTA.

Is there a way to hook into the main STA thread, or will I have to create a new thread and specify STA? If that's the case, how can I set the callback function up to return my HTML the way `Response.Write` currently does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be useful:

[How to run something in the STA thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378016/how-to-run-something-in-the-sta-thread)

Perhaps you could make the call to...

```
html = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtf);
```

...on a different thread in the same way?

```
string rtf;

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   if (context.Request.Form.Count > 0)
   {
      rtf = context.Request.Form[0];
      string html = "";
      if (rtf != "")
      {
         Thread thread = new Thread(ConvertMarkup);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
      }
      if (html != "")
      {
         context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
         context.Response.Write(html);
      }
      else
      {
         context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
         context.Response.Write("Error from RTF2HTML");
      }
   }
}

void ConvertMarkup()
{
    markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
     html = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtf);
}
```

Comment: Will execution wait after `thread.Join()` so that the `if (html != '')` line doesn't execute until after `ConvertMarkup()` finishes?

Comment: No problem, glad to help! thread.Join itself signals the calling thread to wait until the thread has finished executing...simple but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Threading; 

    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ProcessRequest)); 

    // Make sure to set the apartment state BEFORE starting the thread. 
    t.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA; 
    t.Start(); 

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       if (context.Request.Form.Count > 0)
       {
        string rtf = context.Request.Form[0];
        string html = "";
        if (rtf != "")
        {
           markupConverter = new MarkupConverter.MarkupConverter();
           html = markupConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(rtf);
        }
        if (html != "")
        {
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
           context.Response.Write(html);
        }
        else
        {
           context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
           context.Response.Write("Error from RTF2HTML");
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: although, obviously this WILL create a new thread, but there is no way around it. There is a lot of Googling you can do to see why this is required for the UI.

Comment: Thanks. One issue - syntax error on the `new ThreadStart` line, "No overload for 'ProcessRequest' matches delegate 'System.Threading.ThreadStart'". Any ideas?

Comment: Yes...sorry my bad. Loose the HttpContext parameter for your function. You can not pass the function a parameter.