# WPF loading Frame async

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have a `TabConrol` that when a user does certain things, a new `TabItem` is programmatically added.  In this tab there is a Frame that will contain the desired `Page.XAML`.  This is all working perfectly like this;

```
private void addNewTab()
{
   TabItem tab = new TabItem();
   Grid g = new Grid();
   Frame f = newFrame();
   g.Children.Add(f);
   tab.Content = g;
   MyTabControl.Items.Add(tab);
   MyTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
}

private Frame newFrame()
{
   Frame f = new Frame();
   //Full logic for Frame removed
   f.Navigate(new MyPage());
   return f;
}
```

Issues is sometimes the loading of the new `Frame` can take sometime. So I wanted to do this async.  So while it loads there could be a loading animation.  I figured that this would work;

```
private async void addNewTab()
{
   TabItem tab = new TabItem();
   Grid g = new Grid();

   var test = Task<Frame>.Factory.StartNew(() => newFrame(selectTab, value));
   await test;
   f = test.Result;

   g.Children.Add(f);
   tab.Content = g;
   MyTabControl.Items.Add(tab);
   MyTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
}

private Frame newFrame()
{
   Frame f = new Frame();
   //Full logic for Frame removed
   f.Navigate(new MyPage());
   return f;
}
```

Problem is that it returns the follow error on `Frame f = new Frame();` in `newFrame()` at run;

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The calling thread must be STA, because many
>   UI components require this.

Starting to think I am trying to solve this the wrong way.  What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run something in the STA thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378016/how-to-run-something-in-the-sta-thread)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building any reasonable UI is an extremely fast operation. However, determining the *data* to display in that UI can take any amount of time. So I assume that's what's actually slow.

You can't build the actual UI components on a background thread; that's what the exception tells you.

But you can build the *data* on the background thread and then later *load* it into the UI:

```
private async Task addNewTabAsync()
{
  TabItem tab = new TabItem();
  Grid g = new Grid();

  var data = await Task.Run(() => getData(value));
  Frame f = new Frame();
  // Fill out frame with data.
  f.Navigate(new MyPage());

  g.Children.Add(f);
  tab.Content = g;
  MyTabControl.Items.Add(tab);
  MyTabControl.SelectedItem = tab;
}
```

Note that I changed `async void` to `async Task` (and added the `Async` suffix), and changed `StartNew` to `Run` to follow best practices.