# How to run a server function as STAThread?

Tags: c#

I have a function in my controller class - that is working with xml format file
something like

```
public URI convertXML(Uri pathToFile)
{
  // conversion goes here
}
```

and I dlike to run it as

```
[STAThread]
   public URI convertXML(Uri pathToFile)
    {
      // conversion goes here
    }
```

something like

```
 public ActionResult DoTheThingsRight()
 {
      //...
      var resultingURI = [as STAThread] convertXML(filePath); 
 }
```

I have found [How to run something in the STA thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378016/how-to-run-something-in-the-sta-thread)
 But I dont understand what is `GetFooFromAsyncResult` in this sample, so 
perhaps there is another easy way to do this?

Comment: Step back a second - *why* do you want to run this code on an STA thread? If it's because something's throwing an error/exception and saying it has a problem with not being on an STA thread, it probably means that the component/function exposing this error just plain won't work well in a service context. Trying to force yourself onto an STA thread won't (generally) fix the larger problem.

Comment: a DependencyObject that I am trying to parse (Canvas) is required to be created in a Single Thread Affinity context. I should mark the thread as STAThread

Comment: [Single-Thread *Apartments*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx) are a COM concept. You should not take lightly marshaling and unmarshaling COM objects between threads. Perhaps can you achieve the desired result while leaving COM out of the picture? Please read [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms809971.aspx)

Comment: [This Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's not been designed to work in a service context.

Comment: The [STAThread] attribute is only valid on the Main() entrypoint of a program.  STA is a property of a thread, it makes a **promise**.  You must implement the promise, you must never block the thread and run a dispatcher loop (Application.Run).  Breaking the promise causes deadlock.  And various .NET classes to complain, especially in WPF.  A service is a pretty hostile place for WPF classes, maybe you ought to use Bitmap.