# ManagementObjectSearcher does not work within global hook

Tags: c#, com, wmi, pinvoke, mousekeyhook

When I try to get all running processes inside mouse event handler it throws an exception. First I thought that the problem persists because I put `async` keyword before mouse event handler, but it was not the case, as the exception is thrown also for non-asynchronous methods.

I'm using [MouseKeyHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) library.

*Exception message:*

> Additional information: Transition into COM context 0x1ac936a0 for
>   this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: An
>   outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an
>   input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D
>   (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL)).

*Event handler from which I'm getting all processes:*

```
private async void MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    List<ProcessInfo> allRunningProcesses = Logic.GetAllProcesses();
    // ...
}
```

*Get all processes by using `ManagementObjectSearcher`:*

```
public static List<ProcessInfo> GetAllProcesses()
{   
     using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
            using (var results = searcher.Get()) // EXCEPTION THROWN!
            {
                // ...
            }
}
```

As you can see the exception is thrown when calling `searcher.Get()`. **Note:** This method works without any issues if used outside the mouse event handler (`MouseUp`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, COM requires you to run your code on STA if there is MTA
involved and you are using the `ManagementObjectSearcher` methods within `SendMessage()`.
 So, what I needed to do is to run my code on
differet thread and set `SetApartmentState` to `ApartmentState.STA`.

```
List<ProcessInfo> allRunningProcesses = null;

Thread threadProc = new Thread(() =>
{
    allRunningProcesses = Logic.GetAllProcesses();
});

threadProc.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
threadProc.Start();
threadProc.Join();
```

Useful links: 
msdn- [Understanding and Using COM Threading Models](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx)
stackoverflow- [How to run something in the STA thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2378077/2259618)